# Sobre API do Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter-api

gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar?

É o seguinte preciso pegar algumas informações de um determinado usuário do Twitter para introduzi-las em site HTML, gostaria que você por Java script, o grande problema é que não sei por onde começar e não tenho muito conhecimento em js e API.

Comment: Queres fazer isso no lado do cliente ou servidor (Node.js)?

Comment: @Sergio Acho que Node.js não faz tanta diferença de JS, ambos funcionam em ambos porque quase todas funções e objetos globais são idênticos(as). A diferença é que o Node.js tem a função `require` e um tal de objeto de `exports` que permite trazer propriedades de um script para outro com o uso de `require` (nunca aprendi e nunca escrevi Node.js, então me desculpe se meus termos estão errados).